# Can't install software from repository

Tags: apt, google-chrome

I want to play games from mini clip website, tried it in Firefox. Even though it has flash player installed through software center, the games are not working. I tried chromium, but was unable to install flash. Tried to follow the methods already explained in forums.

`sudo apt-get update` replies with a lot of errors like this:

> W: Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en
>   Unable to connect to pk.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

Please help me to install Google Chrome with Flash Player.

Comment: I don't thin Ubuntu has pakistan mirrors, so how did you change your mirror list in first place? 

Try to use the main mirror. Go to Software center, Edit menu, Sources, the very first tab.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Chrome's website and download the official .deb file
Use Gdebi package installer to install the deb file.
You can install it also from the software centre.

PS - chrome already comes with pepper flash an open source flash player so no need for adobe's.